# Executing JavaScript after X seconds

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am building a interstitial page, using <div> and JavaScript, really simple script but neat.

Everything is working, but I also would like to close the div's after a few seconds (like 10 seconds, for example). Here what I have so far:

- I have two div's, 1 and 2.
- I have the CSS setup for div 1 like: display: none; (div 1 have the content for the splash screen)
- Div 2 is the layer that will cover the page and leave only div 1 visible.

To load the div's I have a onload function like this:

```
onload="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block'"
```

To hide the divs I have an onclick function like this:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none'"></a>
```

How can I execute the onclick function with a timer, and how can I do it? It also has to be in JavaScript.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function.

To make your code a little neater, define a separate function for onclick in a `<script>` block:

```
function myClick() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
    }, 5000);
}
```

then call your function from `onclick`

```
onclick="myClick();"
```

Comment: I don't understand, you just said you are doing it in onclick? Are we missing something?

Comment: Second. how can I execute the function myClick without have to use the onclick, onload, etc. I would like to start the function at the same time O load the code

Comment: old question but best solution is - insert ``` myclick();``` also in script tag this will automatically trigger myclick function as soon as document started loading and as defination of function it will be executed after 5 second

Answer (score 15):

setTimeout will help you to execute any JavaScript code based on the time you set.

Syntax

```
setTimeout(code, millisec, lang)
```

Usage,

```
setTimeout("function1()", 1000);
```

For more details, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Note that using the overload to provide the function using a string is considered bad practice. You're better off using `setTimeout(function1, 1000);` or `setTimeout(function() { function1(); }, 1000);` or `setTimeout(() => function1(), 1000);` depending on the nature of `this` references in `function1`. Also, I prefer using [MDN's `setTimeout` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Answer (score 5):

```
onclick = "setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none'}, 1000)"
```

Change 1000 to the number of milliseconds you want to delay.