# If after x seconds call function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code here that on click one pulls one function and on click 2 pulls another function.

How can i make it so after X amoutn of seconds if i am on stop_autoslide function that i can call start_autoslide?

```
<script>
    var count = 0;

function function1(){
    stop_autoslide()
    count++;
}

function function2(){
     start_autoslide();
     count = 0;
}

function slideShowClicks(){
     if(count ==0){
         function1();
     }else{
         function2();
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252638/executing-javascript-after-x-seconds/8252675#8252675

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You setInterval function.

```
setInterval(function_name, time_in_milli_sec);
```

Comment: Where do i exactly add that can u show an example with the code i have?

Answer (score 6):

```
var t = setTimeout(function2, 2000);
```

This will call function2 after 2s (2000ms).

You can then use `t` to cancel the timeout, etc.

**Edit:**

```
function function2(){
     start_autoslide();
     var t = setTimeout(function2, 2000);
}
```

This way, `function2()` will get executed every 2 seconds after you call it from `slideShowClicks()` the first time.

Comment: So replace     `var count = 0; `with that?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I'll edit my answer to explain what happens there.

Comment: If you want to call function2() after 2 seconds from where you have `var count = 0`, then yes :)

Comment: Where do i exactly add that can u show an example with the code i have?

Comment: See my edited answer. If that's not what you want, clarify your requirements and I'll guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

add to your `stop_autoslide()` function

```
  var timeout=setTimeout("start_autoslide()",3000);
```

replace 3000 it 3 sec

with amount of sec you want

Comment: Where exactly do i add that inside?