# How to use smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my testsite http://snapsite.byethost22.com (or via http://robinvandernoord.nl) I'm trying to automatically scroll a little bit down after a couple of seconds.

It should scroll to `#image` in a couple of second, and scroll fluently.

I tried it with `meta refresh` but it kept refreshing, and it's not smooth.

So my question is: can I do it in another way?

Comment: Yes, with javascript (as indicated in your tag). Did you try using it? What did you achieve?

Comment: is it really possible to scroll with `meta refresh`?

Comment: Well I saw something on the web but I have so many javascript already I don't know if it is going to mix up and act weird and all...

Comment: I found out it is not possible to scroll with meta refresh...
At least not in my case

Comment: @dude Yes, by specifying a fragment identifier, however it will only jump to the element rather than 'smoothly scrolling'.

Comment: And I also have many anchors already on my page so I don't know if it is going to work and all...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it with

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#image img").offset().top
      });
    },
  2000);
```

Read this answer for more information: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6677035/938236) and this: [Executing JavaScript after X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8252638/938236)

Comment: Ctrl + C, go to your page, F12, Ctrl + V in the bottom console line of the "Console" section (in firefox). Takes 10 seconds (;

Comment: I can't do F12 and ctrl: I'm on a mac ;)

Comment: Okay it works when I do it offline but when I put it online it doesn't work (at http://snapsite.byethost22.com )

Comment: O it does work at http://van-der-noord.nl/beta so it's probably a problem with the host

Answer (score 0):

Super Easy, use: [smooth-scroll.js](http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/)

How to use: [Read Me](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#readme)

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems. Just follow the Readme, It's 3 steps. :)