# How to change text after X seconds? HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want a text to change after three seconds once the user has clicked. I want that the user clicks and put some text in the screen (this already works) and after three seconds the text changes to nothing (""). The code I tried is:

#### JavaScript:

```
function almuerzo() {
    var date = new Date();
    var horas = date.getHours();
    var minutos = (date.getMinutes() < 10? '0' : '')+ date.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = horas + ":" + minutos + " Almuerzo";
}

function cambio() {
    var contador = 0;
    setInterval(cambio, 1000);
    contador++;
    if(contador == 3)
        document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = "";
    }
```

#### HTML:

```
<h1 id="accion" class="t-accion"></h1>
<img src="img/almuerzo.png" class="i-almuerzo" height="100px" onclick="almuerzo()" onclick="cambio()" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [executing javascript after X seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252638/executing-javascript-after-x-seconds)

Comment: Please avoid calling two functions on click of image which i can see the above code.

Comment: @Kris don't want exactly the same but as you wish mate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with only one function. First change the text and use setTimeout to remove the text after three seconds.

Like:

```
var timeout;
function changeText() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("accion");

  var date = new Date();
  var horas = date.getHours();
  var minutos = (date.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getMinutes();

  elem.innerHTML = horas + ":" + minutos + " Almuerzo";

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest I found is to just declare one function and erase the text in an anonymous function

```
function almuerzo() {
    var date = new Date();
    var horas = date.getHours();
    var minutos = (date.getMinutes() < 10? '0' : '')+ date.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = horas + ":" + minutos + " Almuerzo";

    setTimeout(() => {document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = ""}, 3000);
}
```

Some explanations:

The point is cambio is a hand-made setInterval but you did some mistakes:

`setInterval(cambio, 1000)` cambio without () is an [Object: function] (do a typeof(cambio) & typeof(cambio()) to see the difference) so you're not calling the function you won't have the return value from its call !

Moreover, remember that setInterval make the execution of a function asynchronous, so in your code, it set contador to 0, then launch an other instance (if you had put brackets to cambio) then increments by 1 and leave the execution. The 2nd instance will set contador to 0 and launch another isntance and so on...

```
function cambio() {
    var contador = 0; 
    setInterval(cambio, 1000); /* relaunch asynchronously cambio, 
    reset contador to 0, then relaunch cambio, etc...*/

    contador++;                 // contador === 1

    if(contador == 3)           /* it will never be triggered
    because in each instance of cambio that will run in parallel,
    cambio value will be equal to 1 */
        document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = "";

    }
```

Comment: It's `setInterval(cambio, 1000);` without parentheses

Comment: but it won't call function that way, isn't it?

Comment: It call the function cambio every 1 second. You can use this syntax to `setInterval(function () { cambio(); }, 1000)`

Comment: Oh ok nice, just thought you were saying cambio without parenthesis still works inside setInterval() thanks for the explanations anyway

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use recursion on the `cambio` function, but it reinitialize its `contador` variable each time it's called, so the `contador == 3` condition will never be true.

I don't see the point in waiting 3 times for 1 second instead of 1 time for three seconds. If there is no additional action to be taken each second, just do your action after a single wait :

```
function cambio() {
    setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = "";
    }, 3000);
}
```

If there is indeed a point which your code doesn't show yet, you will want to define your `contador` variable outside of the function scope. Moreover, the counter should be incremented before recursing, and no recursion should be done if the target value has been reached :

```
var contador = 0;
function cambio() {
    if(contador == 3) {
        document.getElementById("accion").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        contador++;
        setInterval(cambio, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't set text to nothing, it remains as it was onclick, if the counter works fine shouldnt be disappearing in 3 seconds?

Comment: @almartinez it should. Make sure you're using the last version of my answer, I edited a few mistakes