# automatic popup box to open after the user spends 10 seconds on the page

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I would like an automatic popup box to open after the user spends 10 seconds on the page. This is the JavaScript code that I have so far in my HTML document. What can I add to it to make the box appear after 10 seconds?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

window.onload = function () {
modal.style.display = "block";};

span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";};

window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";} }
</script>
```

Comment: research about https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing JavaScript after X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252638/executing-javascript-after-x-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }, 10);
```

}